# How to list all excel current regions in one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In order to navigate through complex spreadsheets that I'm asked to analyse I need a list of all current regions in a worksheet. Excel help does not give me many clues. My solution so far is to loop over areas using the special cells function, but it is rather slow.

```
Function list_all_current_regions(work_sheet)
     Dim current_region_dic As New Dictionary
     Set r = work_sheet.Cells(1, 1)
     For Each x In Array(xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Set c = work_sheet.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(x, 23)
        For Each a In c.Areas
           If Not current_region_dic.Exists(a.CurrentRegion.Address) Then
              current_region_dic.Add a.CurrentRegion.Address, ""                  
           End If
        Next
     Next
     Set list_all_current_regions = current_region_dic

End Function
```

Is there a smarter way to list all the current regions in a worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I've avoided having multiple ranges on Worksheets for the very reason you are asking about, and I move disconnected content onto its own Worksheet when a client gives me a model designed as a single "ubersheet".

The only way around this I've found is to use Named Ranges.  They are accessed using the Names collection attached to the Workbook and Worksheet objects.

One other tip I'll give is to just used the Named Range on the top left cell only then you can use the CurrentRegion property to grab the entire range.  This helps when you have expanding regions that you don't want to go in to set and reset the entire range.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In this particular case I have to work with 'legacy' spreadsheets that I cannot change unfortunately, but generally this seems a sound advice that I will keep in mind.

Comment: The .CurrentRegion property may gather cells up and/or to the right if not isolated into a data 'island'.